# Server 18.04.3: Boot problems, corrupted files or faulty GRUB

Tags: grub2, files, filesystem, bootloader

I'm in a bind and curious on suggestions. I have been looking for solutions for days and found nothing that works.

Back story - I tried to clone my boot OS drive to another drive inside the same machine. After this, I cannot properly boot up my server machine. It always boots only Emergency Mode. I can see through the Terminal however that my OS file system appears generally intact.

After running 'journalctl -xb' from Emergency Mode, I see listed in red something along the lines of "couldnt get size MODSIGN couldnt get UEFI db list."

I don't yet understand if this is a faulty grub bootloader issue, or if part of the internal filesystem has become corrupted. Any ideas on where to start? I'd really love to not need to start fresh with a clean install.

A) Ubuntu Server 18.04.3

B) Server

C) Boot drive is Samsung 850 EVO 250GB 3D V-NAND SATA III 6GB/s 2.5" Internal Solid State Drive. Backup drive, cloned from Samsung 850 EVO to this one is Seagate IronWolf ST6000VN0041. I have since removed this drive from the machine. One other similar Seagate drive remains inside the machine, containing my trove of files.

D) Best of my knowledge, source drive that will now not boot is UEFI.

E) Destination drive - not sure of UEFI or Legacy. This is where it gets over my head.

F) Tried to clone with Rescuezilla/ReDo Backup bootable USB. Had cloned to an external portable drive, and attempted to restore to above-mentioned Seagate Ironwolf drive. This is when my problems began.

G) sudo parted -l shows the following

'** Number Start   End     Size   File System Name         Flags
    1      1049kB   538 MB  537 MB fat32       EFI System Partition boot,

```
                                                                 esp
2      538 MB   1305 MB 768 MB ext2    

3      1305 MB  250 GB                      lvm  **'
```

..Worth mentioning that "lvm" thing was one of the first error messages being flashed at me upon trying to reboot on Sunday morning.

Pardon the formatting in answer to G - I cannot find a way to make this miserable gods-awful HTML formatter comply.

Comment: Thank you K7AAY, I have edited my OP to include that info.

Answer (score 0):

Solved booting problem by editing /etc/fstab to reflect current internal drive setup. Machine now boots up.